# OS Error using SQL Server CE 3.5 on Windows 8 (desktop NOT Metro)

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-ce

I'm getting an exception when trying to connect to a SQL Server CE database.

`OS Error: The OS storage system (RAM, CF, SD, or IPSM) is not responding.`

The database seems to be valid, I can open it and browse it in Visual Studio.

Is SQL Server CE 3.5 supported on Windows 8?

Comment: Apparently you need 3.5 SP2, according to [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/8eb08bef-1e76-4cb9-8c00-f2f266a41be4).

Comment: SP2 is the version I'm using. I'll create a post on that forum though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That't the error you get when the connection string points to a database file on a drive that doesn't exist on your computer.

Connection string was pointing at D: instead of C: